# C# using array of Strings for reflection?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to Split a search string containing `Id=23||Header=This is a header||Description=This is a description` into two arrays which I can use in the following context `c.item[i] = property[i]`. I attempted the solution below, but it does not match on the types any help would be appreciated :)

```
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"||"};

        string[] testvalues = selectedSavedSearch.SearchString.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();

        string[] items = new string[testvalues.Count()] ;
        string[] properties = new string[testvalues.Count()] ;

        for (int i = 0; i < testvalues.Count(); i++)
        {
            string[] values;
            values = testvalues[i].Split('=').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
            if (values.Count() > 0)
            {
                items[i] = values[0];
            }
            if (values.Count() > 1)
            {
                properties[i] = values[1];
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
        {
            currentSearch = typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString()).GetValue(properties[i], null);
        }
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Does this problem have to do with the string parsing or the reflection part?  It sounds like it's the reflection part... If that's the case, please edit your question to be limited to that.  The string parsing part just complicates your question

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the class `BugManagerQueryOptions`

Comment: Also, for an array, use `Length` instead of `Count()`

Comment: The exception that is thrown is System.Reflection.TargetException occurred Message=Object does not match target type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misusing the GetValue:

```
currentSearch = typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString()).GetValue(properties[i], null);
```

Here's one way to get the value of the property via reflection:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i]);

// query is the instance of BugManagerQueryOptions that you're trying to get the value from
var value= property.GetValue(query, null);
```

You're passing the property value to property.GetValue which will likely throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, this was just me having a derpy moment and using GetValue when I meant set ... for anyone else solution would be...

`typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString()).SetValue(currentSearch, properties[i], null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UnitTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BugManagerQueryOptions bmqo = new BugManagerQueryOptions
            {
                Id = 64,
                Header = "This is a header, that has not been set by reflection (yet)",
                Description = "This is a description that has not been set by reflection (yet)"
            };

            var pairs = "Id=23||Header=This is a header||Description=This is a description"
                .Split(new string[] { "||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(q => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(q.Split('=')[0], q.Split('=')[1]));

            // TEST : Getting values from the BugManagerQueryOptions instance (bmqo)
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in pairs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(pair.Key).GetValue(bmqo, null));
            }

            // TEST : Setting values to the BugManagerQueryOptions instance (bmqo)
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in pairs)
            {
                if (typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(pair.Key).PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                {
                    typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(pair.Key).SetValue(bmqo, Int32.Parse(pair.Value), null);
                }
                else
                {
                    typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(pair.Key).SetValue(bmqo, pair.Value, null);
                }
            }

            // TEST: Getting values from the BugManagerQueryOptions instance (bmqo) AFTER being set by reflection
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> pair in pairs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(pair.Key).GetValue(bmqo, null));
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class BugManagerQueryOptions
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public String Header { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```